# I want to get all of the allowed values of a field

Tags: 7, entities, database

Let's say I have a field in Drupal called `resource_type`, and I wanted to get all allowed values. Is there any easy way to do this with a command, or do I have to do a database query? I'm not seeing anything specifically that would make this easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For list type field you can use [list_allowed_values](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7) function , You can also use [field_info_field($field_name)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) for more details about field.

```
$my_field = field_info_field('field_resource_type');
$allowed_values= list_allowed_values($my_field);
```

Comment: Hrm, when I am using list_allowed_values, it keeps giving me a "cannot use string offset as array" error. My syntax is as follows:

$list_allowed = list_allowed_values("field_resource_type");

Comment: Can you try Updated solution ?